# UWP CreateFileAsync thread exits when compiled in release mode with Compile with .NET Native tool chain checked

Tags: c#, .net, multithreading, uwp, .net-native

I have a UWP app and I am trying to save a config file using the below code.  This works fine with Compile with .NET Native tool chain unchecked and in debug mode.  However once Compile with .NET Native tool chain is checked the thread exits when trying to create the file.  How do I get around this?

```
public async void SaveConfig()
{
    // serialize JSON to a string
    string json = JsonConvert.SerializeObject(uris);

    // write string to a file
    var file = await ApplicationData.Current.LocalFolder.CreateFileAsync("config.json", CreationCollisionOption.ReplaceExisting);
    await FileIO.WriteTextAsync(file, json);
}
```

Comment: Look at [rd.xml](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/framework/net-native/runtime-directives-rd-xml-configuration-file-reference) for your serialization types

Comment: Have you checked the local folder `C:\Users\xxx\AppData\Local\Packages\.....(your package name)......\LocalState`? With my testing, your code actually has been executed.

Comment: I'm running it inside a service using the Template10 project. I'll check if that might be having side effects

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The problem is most likely to be in the ***async void*** method which isn't awaited to be executed till the end. If this is the case, the solution would be to change the method header

```
public async Task SaveConfigAsync()
```

and invoke the method like this

```
await SaveConfigAsync();
```